# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got this error on 2 of my pages and I can't understand why. I have rewritten the code and triple checked it, but I can't find what is wrong.

The first one is:

```
 public function academics ($id,$problem_solving ,  $math_understanding,      $cs_understanding ,   $math_useful ,  $cs_useful, $math_ava,  $cs_ava,    $assigment_start,   $assigment_submit,  $travel_time,   $stress,$assigment_when,    $full_part,     $pair_programming,  $attending_class,   $attending_labs,$attending_tutorials,   $extra_reading, $p_progamming,  $q_cs,  $q_maths,   $procrastinating_assigments,    $procrastinating_studying){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE student_data SET problem_solving=:problemS, math_understanding=:math_U, cs_understanding=: cs_u, math_useful =:m, cs_useful=:cs_u, math_ava=:ma, cs_ava=:ca, assigment_start=:ass_st, assigment_submit=:assigment_submit, travel_time =:travel_time, stress=: stress, assigment_when =:assigment_when, full_part =:full_part, pair_programming=: pair_programming,   attending_class=: attending_class, attending_labs=: attending_labs, attending_tutorials =:attending_tutorials, extra_reading =:extra_reading, p_progamming=: p_progamming,  q_cs=: q_cs,    q_maths=: q_maths, procrastinating_assigments=:procrastinating_assigments, procrastinating_studying=:procrastinating_studying WHERE user_id=:uid");
        $stmt->bindparam(":uid", $id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":problemS",$problem_solving );
        $stmt->bindparam(":math_U",$math_understanding);
        $stmt->bindparam(":cs_u",$cs_understanding );
        $stmt->bindparam(":m",$math_useful );
        $stmt->bindparam(":cs_u",$cs_useful);
        $stmt->bindparam(":ma",$math_ava);
        $stmt->bindparam(":ca",$cs_ava);
        $stmt->bindparam(":ass_st",$assigment_start);
        $stmt->bindparam(":assigment_submit",$assigment_submit);
        $stmt->bindparam(":travel_time",$travel_time);
        $stmt->bindparam(":stress",$stress);
        $stmt->bindparam(":assigment_when",$assigment_when);
        $stmt->bindparam(":full_part",$full_part    );
        $stmt->bindparam(":pair_programming",$pair_programming);
        $stmt->bindparam(":attending_class",$attending_class);
        $stmt->bindparam(":attending_labs",$attending_labs);
        $stmt->bindparam(":attending_tutorials",$attending_tutorials);
        $stmt->bindparam(":extra_reading",$extra_reading);
        $stmt->bindparam(":p_progamming",$p_progamming);
        $stmt->bindparam(":q_cs",$q_cs);
        $stmt->bindparam(":q_maths",$q_maths);
        $stmt->bindparam(":procrastinating_assigments",$procrastinating_assigments);
        $stmt->bindparam(":procrastinating_studying",$procrastinating_studying);
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }  
}
```

The second one is:

```
public function comps ($id,$long,$often_comp,$gaming,$research,$doc,$music,$vid,$fix,$social){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE student_data SET long=:long, often_comp=:often , gaming=:gaming, research=:research, doc=:doc, music=:music, vid=:vid, fix=:fix, social=:social  WHERE user_id=:uid");
        $stmt->bindparam(":uid",$id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":long",$long);
        $stmt->bindparam(":often",$often_comp);
        $stmt->bindparam(":gaming",$gaming);
        $stmt->bindparam(":research",$research);
        $stmt->bindparam(":doc",$doc);
        $stmt->bindparam(":music",$music);
        $stmt->bindparam(":vid",$vid);
        $stmt->bindparam(":fix",$fix);
        $stmt->bindparam(":social",$social);
        $stmt->execute(); 
    } catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Typo, maybe `: cs_u`? You also use that name twice..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: ^ that being `long` which is a MySQL reserved word and may be closed because of it. If someone pops in an answer for it, I'll close it with that possible dupe.

Comment: @chris85 yeah.... IF that's a typo. See my comment(s) ^

Comment: then there's `: q_cs` also, another space. and `: stress` - Edit: @chris85 this just gets better, *don't it?*

Comment: THANK YOU!!  i had no idea spaces count for php, thought it ignored them like for C/C++, works now.  thank you all again!!

Comment: @bandos you're welcome, but that isn't the only thing wrong with your code. The MySQL reserved word being `LONG`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is too long for a comment (no pun intended on that "long" btw).

Seeing that IF those are **not** typos (and I hope they're not), you have quite a few binds that have spaces after the colon.

You need to delete the spaces for them and also wrap the MySQL reserved word in ticks being `LONG`, or rename it to something other than a reserved word.

I.e.

```
SET `long`=:long, ...
```

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

---

**Footnotes:**

TBH: I didn't count all your binds, so if I missed something, you'll need to go over them all and make sure they all match.

---

**Edit:**

> *"i had no idea spaces count for php, thought it ignored them like for C/C++, works now. thank you all again!! – bandos"*

- This isn't C/C++, it's PHP and spaces do count in that language.

Comment: i got it, thanks. i had thought of long being a keyword in php but it wasnt, didnt think of it being a part of the database section.  that along with the spaces fixed both. thanks again for the help!

Comment: spaces do not count in c/c++, they are ignored at compile time unless it is a hard coded string